# how to trigger all underlying buttons when dragging finger on screen react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am building a RN app. I have a page that displays some times in the week. The user clicks all the times they are free in. (Look at photo for visual representation)

Instead of having the user individually click on all the squares, how can you create a functionality where they can click on many squares at once by dragging their finger from the start square to the end one. Almost like how a mouse on a computer would work

Basically the question really is, if I drag my finger on the screen, how can i trigger all buttons I drag my finger across

[image]

This is not my project but the time slots kind of look like this

Comment: Have you looked into `react-native-gesture-handler` and creating a `GestureDetector` and a `.Pan()` gesture or something of the sort?

Comment: I've just looked into it, max i can do with it is keep track of the coordinate of the drag. Don't know how that would allow me to trigger onPress functions for each little square @Harrison

Comment: hmmm, after giving it a little thought, maybe a workaround would be to use the coordinates of user touches instead of triggering `onPress`?

Comment: @Harrison Could be a shout. Let me try that and will let you know. Thank you

Comment: I was thinking of calculating the squares covered in one drag using the coordinates and then using set state to declare all those squares as chosen. I could also still use touchable opacity on the squares which would allow me to get the best of both worlds